# TPopupMenu subclassing inside a package breaks IDE's popup menus handling after installing

Tags: delphi, package, components, subclass, popupmenu

I'm making a component where I need to handle custom painting of a TPopupMenu class, especially including non-client area of a popup window. So, I did some subclassing as recommended on the internet. But with one difference, my subclass source unit is inside a package. And while testing I discovered that immediatly after installing this package, my IDE's popup menus stop working, they are showing and looking ok, but not all commands now make what they suppose to do. Most of them do nothing at all after clicking on them. Can anybody check if my discovery is right or maybe my code is somehow wrong, but I don't think so, because it is very simple test case. I've checked this behavior under Delphi 2010 and 10.3.3. Both do the same in my test.

Thank You.

Test code (remember to put it in a package, and just install this package into Delphi IDE):

```
unit uPopupListSubclass;

interface

implementation

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Messages,
  Windows,
  Menus;

type
  TPopupListEx = class(TPopupList)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

{ TPopupListEx }

procedure TPopupListEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
end;

initialization
  PopupList.Free;
  PopupList := TPopupListEx.Create;

end.
```

IMPORTANT INFO:
To remove this package You must go to menu: Component -> Install Packages... -> uncheck component -> click Remove button -> click OK button -> restart IDE.

Your IDE might make some AV's along the way uninstalling this package (sorry). But after restart it should work fine, as before.

EDIT:
EDIT2:
Modified source to avoid AV's during removal/disabling of a package.
Added delegation to original popup list.

```
type
  TPopupListAccess = class(TPopupList);

var
  OriginalPopupList: TPopupList;

procedure TPopupListEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  TPopupListAccess(OriginalPopupList).WndProc(Message);
  inherited;
end;

initialization
  OriginalPopupList := PopupList;
  PopupList := TPopupListEx.Create;

finalization
  PopupList.Free;
  PopupList := OriginalPopupList;
```

Comment: Note that once your package is installed in the IDE and then removed/disabled, you are leaking your `TPopupListEx` object, and the IDE/app will continue referring to that object after your package is unloaded from memory. At runtime in your own app, it is safe to subclass `TPopupList` the way you are. But at design-time, you probably shouldn't subclass it at all. But, if you must, then consider saving (rather than freeing) the original object and then restore it in your unit's `finalization`, and maybe even have your object delegate to the original object for any unhandled behaviors.

Comment: Your right Remy, but I didn't think that this is important at this time. How can I know if I'm at design-time and not using any control to did it inside `initialization` section ?

Comment: After modification of source as sugested by Remy, the main culprit remains, IDE's menus are not responding to clicking after my test package is installed into IDE. Any other sugestions, anybody ? And Remy, should I delegate only `WndProc` to orginal `PopupList` class or You were thinking about other functions as well ?

Comment: Inside of a component, it is easy to detect design-time (the `csDesigning` flag will be enabled in the `TComponent.ComponentState` property). But at the unit level, the only reliable way I know to detect whether the package is loaded into the IDE vs an app is to use `ParamStr(0)` to get the path+filename of the calling process and then check it for `bds.exe`.

Comment: Regarding the delegation, have you tried this? `procedure TPopupListEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage); begin OrginalPopupList.WndProc(Message); end;` But I still question the need to subclass `PopupList` **at design-time** to begin with.

Comment: I've tested delegation to original popup list, it is not working in this scenario as well. Remy do You think that hooking `PopupList.Window`  window procedure could do the trick, while being in design-time ?

Comment: You are already hooking the window procedure of `PopupList.Window`, that is what `TPopupList.WndProc()` is.  You are just going to have to actually debug your package's code at design-time (ie, run one instance of the IDE in a 2nd instance's debugger) to see why your code is interfering with the IDE's menu handling. Though,, I *still* question why you are processing menus **at design-time** to begin with. You still have not addressed that.

Comment: FWIW: We're handled the problem by `if not ModuleIsPackage then
    ReplacePopupList;` which works as we don't compile our exes with packages.

Comment: Thanks Uli, it may help me, but I'm now in process of proper refactoring this issue, as SilverWarior said, I did not subclassed this list at all, so I'm working at it now.

Comment: Remy - my goal is not to process menus at design-time, I'm working on component that takes regular `TMainMenu` and can put it on any `TWinControl` descendant that accepts other controls, and I'm interested in processing the view and feel of this `new` menu at run-time, but along the way of making this component I tripped on this issue, where `replacing` original `TPopupList` inside package while designing the component breaks the IDE's menu handling, and I can't work any more, because `Build` command stops working. So I'm kinda debuging the problem using SO, to speed up the process.

Answer (score 3):

You are not subclassing the `TPoputList` correctly. In fact you are not subclassing the `TPopupList` at all but replacing it.

`PopupList` is a global variable declared in `VCL.Menus` unit. So when you call `PopupList.Free` in your `initialization` section you are destrooying the original `PopupList` interface that was created in `VCL.Menus` unit. This is what breaks all PopupMenu's of the whole IDE.

**You should never free an object that you did not create yourself.

Doing so you are interfering and possibly breaking the original code that works with that object.

You should only free objects that you have created yourself.**

Instead what you should od is create your own `PopupListEx` global variable and reference to if from the code in your package instead to original `PopupList` variable.

EDIT: You are lucky that you haven't crashed te IDE entirely with your code as it is interfering with existing IDE code.

Comment: I think using your own variable instead of `Vcl.Menus.PopupList` defeats the purpose of the "subclassing". At least we used this trick to fix incorrect VCL behaviour (`ODS_NOACCEL`).

Comment: `Subclassing` means that you create a new class that encompasses functionality of existing class and extends it further with additional functionality. You do this in order to avoid "reinventing the wheel" by designing the same functionality of some existing class from scratch. Replacing/changing functionality of existing class is not 
 `subclassing`.